# Change "Hamburger Button"

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want change drawer icon back to back arrow and then take default.  So, I have an activity with fragment(1st) that uses **tool bar**(**Hamburger Button**) and **navigation drawer**. I have **2rd fragment**, there is disabled **Navigation Drawer** and disabled **Hamburger button**, but it has "home as up" enabled. When I back to 1st fragment from 2rd, these is **Hamurger Button** doesnt work. What am I doing wrong?
 2rd fragment:

```
 toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
        toggle.syncState();
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
       drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
```

When I return to 1st fragment from 2rd:

```
 toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
```

Answer (score 0):

For enable HomeAsUpButton in your 2nd fragment you must use

```
((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);  

((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

under `onResume()`.

and for remove the arrow icon and again enable the Hamburger icon, use

```
((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);  
((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);

toogle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
```